# Implicit conversion from template method argument's return value

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to build a custom indexing of elements stored in a vector based on their assigned `ID` that does not change. The index might change however hence the indexing.

The template structure is as follows:

```
template<typename Element, typename Index>
class MyStore
{
public:
    //...
    Element get(Index index) const { return data.at(index); }

private:
    QVector<Element> data;
};
```

So in this class I store the elements of arbitrary type in a vector. To retreive them I use a `get` method that takes `Index` argument. `Index` must be of integer type but I cannot use `int` directly because I will be using this for `QFile` storage as well and that uses `qint64` as index hence the template `Index`.

```
   template<typename ID>
   class MyElement
   {
   public:
       //...
       operator ID() const { return m_ID; }

   private:
       ID m_ID;
   };
```

So the `MyElement` uses `ID` as identifier and is implicitly convertible to it. Nothing fancy really. And finally:

```
template<typename ID, typename Index, typename Store, ID (Store::*get)(Index) const>
class MyIndex
{
public:
    //...

private:
    Store *m_Store;
    QVector<Index> m_Index;
};
```

So the `MyIndex` stores merely the vector of `Indexe`s (it is a hash table that uses `ID` to get to the correct slot) and it needs a way to check that the `ID` in a given slot matches hence the `Store` and the `ID` retreival template arguments.

The usage would then be:

```
using TheID = int;
using TheIndex = int;
using TheStore = MyStore<MyElement<ID>, Index>;

TheStore store;
MyIndex<TheID, TheIndex, TheStore, &TheStore::get> idx;
```

Instantiating of the `MyIndex` fails because the compiler does not find a match for the last argument as it complains that it cannot convert anything to `ID` although I do provide implicit conversion from `MyElement` to `ID`.

Is there a way to make this work or do I need to provide an exact method returning `ID` (and not other type, even if it is implicitly convertible to `ID`) as the `Index`'s fourth parameter?

Comment: Why do you need the fourth template parameter ? How are you making use of it or how do you want to make use of it ?

Comment: @Arunmu In traditional hash implementation the key (`ID` in my case) is stored alongside the values in the hash table. To save memory and because I do store the key (`ID`) elsewhere already (in the elements) I chose to retreieve the key from there when needed (when searching in the hash table and doing comparisions). This retreival is templated via `Store` template argument and pointer to its method that would return the `ID`. So the usage `(m_Store->*get)(index) == id;` where index is what is stored in a given position and `id` is what I am searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function pointer or member function pointer types do not convert between each other. Even if the return type in one [member] function pointer is convertible to the return type in another [member] function pointer, they are entirely different entities. You code tries to use

```
MyElement<int> (MyStore<MyElement<int>, int>::*)(int) const
```

where a member function pointer of type

```
int (MyStore<MyElement<int>, int>::*)(int) const
```

is required. Since `int` and `MyElement<int>` are different types they are incompatible without implicit or explicit conversions, even if the return type of the former is convertible to the return type of the latter.